# Uninstall Sphinx On Mac OS X

Tags: macos, search, sphinx

I am trying to uninstall Sphinx 2.0.1 from Mac OS 10.6 to revert back to a previous version.

I installed Sphinx doing a `make install` a few weeks back and in my efforts to get it working, I downloaded multiple versions of Sphinx in multiple directories.

I read deleting the directory you run `make install` from is supposed to remove Sphinx, so I did a search in finder for `sphinx` and `searchd` and deleted all the directories but I still get sphinx results when I type `searchd`.

How would I go about removing my installed version of Sphinx so I can move back to a previous version (installed with homebrew) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since a make install is an adhoc script, it can install files all over your file system. (could)

I suggest you run a 'which sphinx' and remove a few versions, then add the path where homebrew install binaries at the front of your $path variable so the proper version of sphinx will get picked up first.